# Iterate through array denoted by unsigned short pointer

Tags: c++

I have some code that existed in C which contains an array of `uint16_t`, which looks something like `uint16_t *Fingerprints;`. To iterate through it, I can pair it together with a `uint32_t ArrayLength;` value and directly access `Fingerprints[i]`.

Now, I am writing more code in C++ and I have a `std::vector<uint16_t> values` that I want to iterate through the same datatype. Is it possible to get a `uint16_t *` from this and pair it with `values.size()` to iterate through?

Comment: Look at vector member functions. It has its own iterator type as well as begin and (one past last) end functions.

Comment: It's possible, (use `values.data()` or even `&values[0]`) but its normal to use iterators instead (`values.begin()` and `values.end()`). Or to use a [range based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Comment: Note that `unsigned short`, mentioned in the title, is not required to be the same as `std::uint16_t`. `unsigned short` can be larger than 16 bits, and even if it's the same size, if the compiler uses a 16-bit `int` type, `uint16_t` can be `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::vector<uint16_t>` has a `.data()` member function which will give you a `uint16_t*` pointer and which you could use together with `.size()` in the same way you were using it in C.

However, in C++ we usually use iterators instead of pointers if there is no specific reason to use the latter. Iterators are a generalization of the pointer concept which also applies to other kinds of containers. This has the benefit of being agnostic to the container type. If you replaced `std::vector` with `std::list` you wouldn't have to change anything in your code. E.g.:

```
std::vector<uint16_t> values;
// or e.g. `std::list<uint16_t> values`

for(auto it = values.begin(); it != values.end(); ++it) {
    /* You can use `it` here similar to a pointer to the current element */
    /* Meaning `it` is similar to `Fingerprints + i` */
}
```

This also has the benefit that you can't accidentally mismatch the index type. How are you making sure that `uint32_t` is the correct type to use for the index? What if you are on x64 and have an array/vector so large that the size can't fit in `uint32_t`. It should really usually be `std::size_t` (or maybe `std::ptrdiff_t` if signed is preferred) for arrays/vectors instead and for other containers it might vary further.

Furthermore there is the range-for loop syntactical sugar for this which you should prefer you if you just want a simple iteration through all of the container:

```
for(auto&& el : values) {
    /* You can use `el` here as a reference to the current element in the iteration */
    /* Meaning `el` is basically `Fingerprints[i]` */
}
```